# Add value from select multiple form to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

### I have select multiple form like this :

```
<label style="width: 150px; float: left">Co Auditor</label>
<select name="co_auditor_nip[]" multiple = 'multiple' size=6>
<?php
foreach ($co_auditor_nip->result() as $row)
{

    echo '<option value="'.$row->nip.'"';
     if($co_auditor_nip_choosen == $row->nip)
     { 
          echo 'selected="selected"';
     } 

     echo' >'.$row->nama.'</option>';
}
?>
</select><br>
```

And after that i want to insert the value to database with php codeigniter like this :

```
$co_auditor_nips['co_auditor_nip']  = addslashes($this->input->post('co_auditor_nip'));

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO r_audit VALUES (' ', '$company_code', '$company_name', '$branch_code',
        '$branch_name','$business_unit', '$lead_auditor_nip', '$lead_auditor', '$co_auditor_nips', '$co_auditor',
        '$periode_audit_from','$periode_audit_to', '$tanggal_audit_from', '$tanggal_audit_to', '$auditee', '$auditee_jabatan',
        '$auditee_email',
        '$auditee_2','$auditee_2_jabatan' ,'$auditee_2_email', '$cc_email', 'started', '1')");
```

But my result on database for column is just Array (text Array), help me to get the all values, thanks !

Comment: print `$_POST` in controller and check what is coming..

Comment: Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: controllers/apps.php

Line Number: 408 and the result is Array (text Array)

Comment: line number 408 is the query or addslashes() line??

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert an array to db, so it will be good if you use `json_encode()` while inserting and `json_decode()` while retrieval. You can do like this

```
$co_auditor_nips['co_auditor_nip'] = json_encode($this->input->post('co_auditor_nip'));
```

or you can use `implode()' while inserting and`explode()` while retrieving, like this,

```
$co_auditor_nips['co_auditor_nip'] = implode(",",$this->input->post('co_auditor_nip'));
```

To `explode` the value from DB, you can do like this

```
$str = "value from database which is in comma-separated format";
print_r (explode(",",$str));
```

Comment: still not work, i want to insert all values separate by comma on one field

Comment: then you should use `implode()`, i will change my answer for `implode()`

Comment: check if that helps you.

Comment: i have this error message like this Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Filename: controllers/apps.php

Line Number: 328

Comment: print the post values and check if you are getting an array, because, if the value is not an array, you ll get error.

Comment: is `co_auditor_nip` this an array in post??

Comment: array because i use at view like this :  name = co_auditor_nip[] multiple = 'multiple'

Comment: can you give me your script for insertion to database ? i use $co_auditor_nips['co_auditor_nip']  = implode(",",$this->input->post('co_auditor_nip'));  and for insert to database i use : $this->db->query("INSERT INTO r_audit VALUES (' ', '$company_code', '$company_name', '$branch_code',
   '$branch_name','$business_unit', '$lead_auditor_nip', '$lead_auditor', '$co_auditor_nips', '$co_auditor',
   )");

Comment: i have no error anymore, but still my nip_co_auditor field is "Array" i want to get the value example : 0981,0982 etc

Comment: $co_auditor_nips = implode(",",$this->input->post('co_auditor_nip'));

Comment: remove the index for the variable `$co_auditor_nips`

Comment: amazing it works ! :) thanks a lot niranjan, and how about the explode ? i need this to set default ( on update button ), so user can know the previous value that already selected

Comment: and also i have to create input type text with 3 rows : name, job function , and email for auditor identity. but user can add the number of auditor 3 times maximum by press add auditor button. So the input can be dynamic. Can i use codeigniter or javascript ?  thanks

Comment: what you can do is, have 3 input type as text name for each as name[],job[],email[]., on click you can in add auditor button, you can append the html to a form and capture their value in controller.

Comment: and how about the explode method ?

Comment: i have added in my answer, juts check with that once

Comment: i try to insert  $str = $this->db->query("SELECT nip_co_auditor FROM r_audit "); $co_auditor_nip_choosen    = explode(",",$str); and i get this error message Severity: Warning

Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Filename: admin/f_audit_add.php

Line Number: 16

Comment: print $str and see, it ll be an object,

Comment: i type like this : $str = $this->db->query("SELECT nip_co_auditor FROM r_audit "); print_r (explode(",",$str));  and still have the same error

Comment: db is returning object, for explode it shub be string. Change your query loke this,
 $str = $this->db->query("SELECT nip_co_auditor FROM r_audit ")->row(); print_r (explode(",",$str->nip_co_auditor));

Comment: i still get many problem at my internal audit process. may i give you the flow chart for share you the pattern ? there is 7 process and i stuck at process 3 and 7